# Coding standards for comparing pointer to NULL

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, coding-style, null

Are there any coding guidelines on what comparison, either:

```
if (ptr != nullptr) ...
```

or

```
if (ptr) ...
```

is better in C++(11)?

This question is not duplicate of [C: Comparison to NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284050/c-comparison-to-null), in the latter it is said that these forms are equivivalent in C.

Neither this question is opition based: I'm not asking of what do you prefer, but whether there are any coding standards or guidelines, which tell to prefer one form or another.

Comment: So you're asking for the opinions of code guideline writers instead of ours?

Comment: Well, actually, yes :) But I think this is a better choice, since guidelines are tools to formalize opinions.

Comment: Or more accurately, guidelines *are* formalized opinions. =P

Comment: There are no official, universal C++ coding standards, so your question cannot be answered. It could be answered for [Sutter/Alexandrescu](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c++cs.htm), for [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/CppConventions), for [Root](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/c-coding-conventions), for [Geosoft](http://geosoft.no/development/cppstyle.html), for [Google](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml)... but not universally.

Comment: If you're asking for _guidelines,_ then it _is_ opinion-based :-) That's what guideline means, a guide rather than a flat-out rule. Even coding "standards" are really guidelines in the context of the ISO standard, which allows you to write your code however you wish, provided it complies.

Comment: Except whose guidelines to use is a matter of opinion...

Comment: The two popular standards or guidelines are: if you work alone - pick the one you like and stick to it; if you're working in a team - follow your colleagues.

Comment: Barring a functional difference between the two (and I can't see how there would be once optimized), there is no "better"; there is only "I like this more.", So I'm not sure this can be answered.

Comment: @WhozCraig Even before optimization.  `if` requires a `bool`.  The conversion of a pointer to `bool` is defined as comparing it to `0` (or any other null pointer constant).  Given `if ( ptr )`, the first thing a compiler will do is convert it into `if ( ptr != 0 )`.

Answer (score 2):

Every coding guideline I've seen insists on

```
if ( ptr != nullptr )
```

or

```
if ( ptr != NULL )
```

in pre-C++11, which is the usual case.  Using `0` instead of
`NULL` is also widespread, and the choice could be considered
a question of style (in the sense that there a valid arguments
for both points of view).

In general, coding guidelines tend to avoid implicit conversions
(with the possible exception of non-lossy conversions, like
`int` to `double`), as they make the code harder to read.

On the other hand, coding guidelines can't avoid ubiquitous
idioms (not the case here), so will generally accept the
implicit conversion of a stream to a type which can act as
a boolean.  (Part of the motivation here is probably the fact
that the alternatives that programmers come up with are
generally wrong.  Better an implicit conversion which works than
code which doesn't.)

Answer (score 0):

As i got it right in the c++11 standard nullptr isn't handled as a numeric value, so it isn't `0` as the NULL define in C is. It's more just NULL in a own way and won't be treat as the numeric `0`, mostly to avoid missmatches with templates.

So it would probably be prefered asking for

`if (ptr != nullptr) ...` as

`nullptr` isn't called to be NULL in any way.

Comment: `nullptr` isn't called to be NULL in any way - what do you mean?

Comment: I want to say, that nullptr is equvivalent to "Nothing" in vba. What is kind of different to the NULL we know in C as far i know vba well enough. so nullptr and NULL arent the same. and nullptr isn't to be interpreted as numeric `0` as the define of NULL is. or am I wrong?

Comment: No, `nullptr` will not be treated as numeric `0`.

Comment: So why downvoting? thats exactly what I said.

Comment: Maybe you forgot a "not" somewhere, then.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes The fact that `nullptr` will not be treated as numeric 0 is, in fact, the very motivation for its existence.  (And the reason that `NULL` is not `nullptr` is because doing so would break existing code.  Code that I'd be in favor of breaking, but I didn't make that decision.)

Comment: True story, I'm sorry yeah i wrote will and not won't v.v

Comment: You're right, but this is not an answer to my question. I was asking about guidelines and recommendations, not about how `nullptr` works.

Comment: @Mikhail it is in so far answering your question, as nullptr isn't to be a bool value in any case, so the if statement would probably be never accpeting just a value of `nullptr` and this would get corrected on compilation, so my answer was, -> its prefered to write the comparrison out as the other way would strictly argumenting be implementation defined. But this is just my opinion, and i guess the standard doesn't says so about the behavior.

Comment: What? It's not implementation defined at all. It's perfectly well-defined and has the same semantics.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes I said, in my own view it could be, but the standard doesn't says so. I never said that it IS implementation defined. "But this is just my opinion, and i guess the standard doesn't says so about the behavior."